# Showing taxes per invoice items from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with getting tax values from database. I will simplify it as possible i can.

First table is

```
Invoices
(
    `Id`, 
    `Date`, 
    `InvoiceNumber`,
    `Total`
)
```

Second table is

```
`InvoiceItems` 
(
    `Id`, 
    `Total`, 
    `TotalWithoutTax`, 
    `TotalTax`,
    `InvoiceId`
)
```

`InvoiceId` is a foreign key for `Id` column from previous table `Invoices`

Third table is

```
`InvoiceItemTaxes` 
(

    `Id`, 
    `TaxAmmount`, 
    `InvoiceItemId`, 
    `TaxId`
)
```

and fourth table

```
`Taxes` 
(
    `Id`,
    `Value`
)
```

This last table contains three taxes, let's say 3, 10 and 15 percent.

I am trying to get something like this - table with columns `InvoiceNumber`, `Total without taxes`, `Tax1`, `Tax2`, `Tax3` and `Total with taxes`.

I tried a lot of different approaches and i simply cannot get tax amount for every invoice. End result would be table where i can see every invoice with specified amounts of every tax (sum of each tax amount for every invoice item).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this easier to understand.  Perhaps you're looking for conditional aggregation (`case` with `max`) to combine the multiple rows in the `Taxes` table for multiple columns in your output . . .

Comment: Okay... Let's say you created invoice with four items - Pencil (3% tax, 1$ without tax), PostIt (3% tax, 2$), Notebook (10%, 5$) and wrap paper (15%, 1$). Each of them would be in `InvoiceItems` table, with they respective values. Also, you would have each of them in `InvoiceItemsTaxes` with only tax amounts. And finally, you would have one entry in `Invoices` - invoice no. 1, total of 9$ without tax).

I am trying to get a list of all invoices with specified how much tax by every rate is paid and total (without tax). How would SQL query go on this example?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use conditional aggregation with `sum` and `case` to get the breakdown by tax group:

```
select i.id, i.invoicenumber, i.total as pretaxtotal,
    sum(case when t.value = 3 then iit.TaxAmmount end) taxes_3,
    sum(case when t.value = 10 then iit.TaxAmmount end) taxes_10,
    sum(case when t.value = 15 then iit.TaxAmmount end) taxes_15,
    sum(ii.Total) as overalltotal
from invoices i 
   join InvoiceItems ii on i.id = ii.invoiceid
   join InvoiceItemTaxes iit on ii.id = iit.InvoiceItemId
   join Taxes t on t.id = iit.taxid
group by i.id, i.invoicenumber, i.total
```

Some of the fields may be a little off -- the sample data was not complete.